# Using JSON in Haskell to Serialize a Record

Tags: json, haskell

I've been working on a very small program to grab details about Half Life 2 servers (using the  [protocol-srcds](https://github.com/b52/protocol-srcds) library).  The workflow is pretty straightforward; it takes a list of servers from a file, queries each of them, and writes the output out to another file (which is read by a PHP script for display, as I'm tied to vBulletin).  Would be nice if it was done in SQL or something, but seeing as I'm still just learning, that's a step too far for now!

Anyway, my question relates to serialization, namely, serializing to JSON.  For now, I've written a scrappy helper function `jsonify`, such that:

```
jsonify (Just (SRCDS.GameServerInfo serverVersion
                           serverName   
                           serverMap    
                           serverMod    
                           serverModDesc
                           serverAppId  
                           serverPlayers
                           serverMaxPlayers 
                           serverBots
                           serverType
                           serverOS  
                           serverPassword
                           serverSecure  
                           serverGameVersioning)) = 
                            toJSObject [ ("serverName", serverName)
                                       , ("serverMap", serverMap)
                                       , ("serverPlayers", show serverPlayers)
                                       , ("serverMaxPlayers", show serverMaxPlayers) ]
```

(I'm using the `Text.JSON` package).  This is obviously not ideal.  At this stage, however, I don't understand using instances to define serializers for records, and my attempts to do so met a wall of frustration in the type system.

Could someone please walk me through the "correct" way of doing this?  How would I go about defining an `instance` that serializes the record?  What functions should I use in the `instance` (showJSON?).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to consider using [`Data.Aeson`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) instead which might be regarded as the successor to `Text.JSON`.

With `aeson` you define separate instances for serialize/deserializing (with `Text.JSON` you have to define both directions even if you need only one, otherwise the compile will annoy you -- unless you silence the warning somehow), and it provides a few operators making defining instances a bit more compact, e.g. the example from @hammar's answer can be written a little bit less noisy as shown below with the `aeson` API:

```
instance ToJSON SRCDS.GameServerInfo where
    toJSON (SRCDS.GameServerInfo {..}) = object
        [ "serverName"       .= serverName
        , "serverMap"        .= serverMap
        , "serverPlayers"    .= serverPlayers
        , "serverMaxPlayers" .= serverMaxPlayers
        ]
```

Comment: Thankyou for that.  I've seen Data.Aeson mentioned, but Text.JSON still seemed to the be the canonical implementation.  I'll try the Data.Aeson package tonight though; that does look remarkably clean :).

Comment: @frio, `Text.JSON` actually has been the "canonical implementation" for a long time... but now a shift is occurring to `Data.Aeson`...

Answer (score 1):

One simple thing you can do is use [record wildcards](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-wildcards) to cut down on the pattern code.

As for your type system problems, it's hard to give help without seeing error messages and what you've tried so far, however I suspect one thing that might be confusing is that the result of `toJSObject` will have to be wrapped in a `JSObject` data constructor as the return type of `showJSON` is supposed to be a `JSValue`. Similarly, the values of your object should also be of type `JSValue`. The easiest way to do this is to use *their* `JSON` instance and call `showJSON` to convert the values.

```
instance JSON SRCDS.GameServerInfo where
    showJSON (SRCDS.GameServerInfo {..}) =
        JSObject $ toJSObject [ ("serverName", showJSON serverName)
                              , ("serverMap", showJSON serverMap)
                              , ("serverPlayers", showJSON serverPlayers)
                              , ("serverMaxPlayers", showJSON serverMaxPlayers) ]
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the pointer to record wildcards - would definitely help me cut back on the boilerplate!

Will try your code shortly, but wrapping the toJSObject output in a JSObject looks like it'd solve one of the (many, fairly random) problems I was having.  Is calling `toJSObject` in a `showJSON` instance a preferred/standard way of serializing records?

Comment: @frio: Any scheme for converting your type to a `JSValue` should be fine as long as your `readJSON` matches the format. `toJSObject` seems like a good fit for record types.